# Can't open Nuxt.js starter template at Cloud9

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cloud9, nuxt.js

Can't open [Nuxt.js starter template](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/) in the browser (I see Cloud9 page: No application seems to be running here! Cloud9 can't get you to your requested workspace...).

Сhosen template is **Blank**.

Node.JS installed by NVM and I choose version v6.10.2 (Latest LTS: Boron)

Little editing *package.json* of nuxt.js starter template, cause default port is `3000`, but in c9 available only `8080`, `8081`, `8082` :

```
  "config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "port": "8080"
       }
  },
```

Then I run app (`npm run dev`) and see everything is ok in console:

```
mytemplateapp@1.0.0 dev /home/ubuntu/workspace/mytemplateapp
> nuxt

nuxt:build App root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/mytemplateapp +0ms
nuxt:build Generating .nuxt/ files... +1ms
Ready on http://127.0.0.1:8080
nuxt:build Generating routes... +14ms 
nuxt:build Generating files... +9ms
nuxt:build Adding webpack middleware... +17
Build completed in 4.204s


DONE  
Compiled successfully in 4210ms                                                                                                                            
Open http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

I've already tried all three available ports.

Well, I am stuck. I would appreciate any advice

Comment: I found main issue: it's adress of host! Should be like http://0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: I stuck at the same point.. please teach me how you fix that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:
1. in your `package.json`

```
"config": {
  "nuxt": {
   "port": 8080,
   "host": "0.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

2. run `npm run dev` (if it doesn't work use `sudo npm run dev`)
3. click the link which shows on cloud9 terminal

then you get it

Comment: This worked. Here some additional docs: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/